# Node.js server and Mongoose connection not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
(node:1256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\cblak\OneDrive\Desktop\WebDevCourse\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:688:11)
    at C:\Users\cblak\OneDrive\Desktop\WebDevCourse\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:348:10      
    at C:\Users\cblak\OneDrive\Desktop\WebDevCourse\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\cblak\OneDrive\Desktop\WebDevCourse\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\cblak\OneDrive\Desktop\WebDevCourse\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1149:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\cblak\OneDrive\Desktop\WebDevCourse\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:347:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cblak\OneDrive\Desktop\WebDevCourse\server.js:18:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1256) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit 
code.
```

Comment: You need to pass the connection string while connecting to MongoDB, add your code to the question.

Comment: Add the connection code please

Comment: hey i got everything fixed so far it looks like, had to add the string. erase the mongodb client and restart computer, and run from mongoose